# Dynamically control TabbedPanel in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make TabbedPannel unseen in the beginning,

Then when certain task is done, I want to show the tabs after that.

[image]

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""

<Test>:
    size_hint: .5, .5
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'first tab'
        Label:
            text: 'First tab content area'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'tab2'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'Second tab content area'
            Button:
                text: 'Button that does nothing'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'tab3'
        RstDocument:
            text:
                '\\n'.join(("Hello world", "-----------",
                "You are in the third tab."))

""")


class Test(TabbedPanel):
    pass


class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

The code above is from the [Kivy Document](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.tabbedpanel.html).

What I am trying to do is

1. Hide tabs (Also prevents moving tabs)
2. When certain action is done, slides the tabs down from the outside of screen.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounded like a fun little challenge, so here is what I came up with:

```
'''
TabbedPanel
============

Test of the widget TabbedPanel.
'''
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel, TabbedPanelStrip
from kivy.lang import Builder


class Test(TabbedPanel):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.initialTabHeight = None
        self.myTabsList = None
        self.start_top = None
        self.tabs_showing = True

        # this TabbedPanelStrip will be a copy of the real one (self._tab_strip)
        self.tmp_tab_strip = TabbedPanelStrip(
            tabbed_panel=self,
            rows=1, size_hint=(None, None),
            height=self.tab_height, width=self.tab_width)

        # this is the movable Widget that contains the tabs
        self.movable_tab_strip = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None), height=self.tab_height)

        # These value are needed to set the width of self.movable_tab_strip, but
        # they aren't always available when self.first is called below
        self._tab_strip.bind(width=self.tab_strip_width_changed)
        self.bind(width=self.panel_width_changed)

        Clock.schedule_once(self.first)

    def tab_strip_width_changed(self, instance, new_width):
        self.movable_tab_strip.width = min(self.tmp_tab_strip.width, self.width)

    def panel_width_changed(self, instance, new_width):
        self.movable_tab_strip.width = min(self.tmp_tab_strip.width, self.width)

    def first(self, *args):
        # show tab2, so that the Button will be available
        self.switch_to(self.parent.ids.tab2)

        # save some info
        self.initialTabHeight = self.tab_height
        self.myTabsList = self.tab_list.copy()

        tsw = 0
        for tab in self.myTabsList:
            if tab.size_hint_x:
                tsw += 100
            else:
                tsw += tab.width
        self.tmp_tab_strip.width = tsw
        self.movable_tab_strip.add_widget(self.tmp_tab_strip)

        # actually remove the tabs
        self.do_clear_widgets()

    def do_clear_widgets(self, *args):
        # eliminate the tabs and populate the moveable_tab_strip
        #self.movable_tab_strip.width = min(self.tmp_tab_strip.width, self.width)
        self.tab_height = 0
        self.clear_tabs()
        for tab in reversed(self.myTabsList):
            self.tmp_tab_strip.add_widget(tab)
        self.tabs_showing = False

    def do_progress(self, animation, widget, progression):
        # grow the tab height when the moveable_tab_strip impinges on the TabbedPanel
        # this has the effect of appearing to shrink the TappedPanel to the size it will have when the tabs are replaced
        if self.start_top > self.movable_tab_strip.y:
            self.tab_height = self.start_top - self.movable_tab_strip.y

    def do_replace_tabs(self, *args):
        # replace the moveable_tab_trip with the actual tabs
        self.tmp_tab_strip.clear_widgets()
        for tab in reversed(self.myTabsList):
            self.add_widget(tab)
        self.tab_height = self.initialTabHeight
        self.parent.remove_widget(self.movable_tab_strip)

    def do_tab_toggle(self, *args):
        if self.tabs_showing:
            self.do_clear_widgets()
        else:
            self.anim = Animation(pos=(self.x+2, self.y + self.height - self.movable_tab_strip.height))
            self.movable_tab_strip.pos = (self.x + 2, App.get_running_app().root_window.height)
            self.start_top = self.top
            self.parent.add_widget(self.movable_tab_strip)
            self.anim.bind(on_progress=self.do_progress)
            self.anim.bind(on_complete=self.do_replace_tabs)
            self.anim.start(self.movable_tab_strip)
            self.tabs_showing = True


class MyLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass


theRoot = Builder.load_string("""

MyLayout:
    Test:
        id: thePanel
        size_hint: .5, .5
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        do_default_tab: False

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'first tab'
            Label:
                id: theLabel
                text: 'First tab content area'
        TabbedPanelItem:
            id: tab2
            text: 'tab2'
            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text: 'Second tab content area'
                Button:
                    text: 'Button that does something'
                    on_press: thePanel.do_tab_toggle()
        TabbedPanelItem:
            id: tab3
            text: 'tab3'
            RstDocument:
                text:
                    '\\n'.join(("Hello world", "-----------",
                    "You are in the third tab."))
        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'tab4'
            Label:
                text: 'This is Tab4'
        TabbedPanelItem:
            id:tab5
            text: 'tab5'
            Label:
                text: 'This is Tab5'

""")


class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return theRoot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

The idea is to create a "movable" tab strip, populate it with the actual tabs from the `TabbedPanel`, and then animate that tab strip. I changed the kv language string to put the whole thing in a `FloatLayout` (I think that makes the `Animation` easier). The `Button`, that formerly did nothing, now toggles the tabs.  In the `do_tab_toggle()` method, I set the x position of the movable tab strip to the x position of the `TabbedPanel` plus 2. The 2 is a fudge factor, and I wasn't able to determine why it is needed, and it may be different for other `TabbedPanel` instances. The "remove" part of the `do_tab_toggle()` could also be animated, but that is left as an exercise for the reader :-)

Other options are to simply clear the tabs using the `clear_tabs()` method, or to animate the `tab_height` property of the `TabbedPanel` (animate the height to zero to hide the tabs).

EDIT: Added a couple bindings to capture data that is not reliably available when the `first` method is called.